# Why @ custom-media does not apply the respective styles in sass

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

I am trying to make a basic layout with CSS grid and the responsive part with the new specification of [CSS level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/) , but it is not working for me when compiling the content of the sass, Am I failing in something? Do I miss any detail?

**custom-media.scss**

```
*{ margin: 0 ; padding: 0}

@custom-media --phone  ( 320px < width < 480px); 
@custom-media --tablets (481px < width  < 767px);
@custom-media --ipad-landscape  (768px < width < 1024px) and (orientation: landscape);
@custom-media --ipad-normal  (768px < width < 1024px);
@custom-media --desktop  (1025px < width  < 1280px);
@custom-media --large  (width > 1281px);
```

**app.scss**

```
@import 'custom-media';

/**
 *
 * Login Page
 *
 */
 .container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 1fr;
    grid-row: 1fr;

    .presentation{
        background:#CB3BBF;
    }

    .loginsection{

    }

    @media  (--desktop) {
        .container {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
        }

        .presentation{
            background:blue;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to have the width between 1025px and 1280 px the blue background color and it does not work **in Chrome Versión 64.0.3282.186**

Comment: Did you install https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
@mixin responsive($size) { @if $size == large { /* 1920px / @media (max-width: 120em) { @content; } } @if $size == small { / 1199px */ @media (max-width: 74.938em) { @content; } } } @include responsive(large){ font-size: 42px; } @include responsive(small){ font-size: 22px; }
```

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Dec 2021), it appears that, while in the spec, @custom-media has not been implemented anywhere yet. Neither [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=custom-media) nor [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=custom-media) know about @custom-media.